# Injecting additional fields in serialization

Tags: java, json, angularjs, rest, jackson

I have objects which I serialize using Jackson. e.g.

```
class A {
    int id;
    String value
}
```

is serialized to:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "value": "test"
}
```

Now I want an **additional field** in the serialized version:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "value": "test"
    "__errors__": [
        { field: "id", "message": "already in use" },
        { field: "value", "message": "field to long" },
    ]
}
```

This field is composed by a list of class Error:

```
class Error {
    String field;
    String message;
}
```

This should be done **while serializing** and **work without adding a method / property** to the class A.

So is there a way to *inject* additional fields into jackson mapper? Best would be a generic method which would work for all classes passed to the mapper without additional code.

(Background: I want to use this to return validation errors to AngularJS within the normal result. Because putting both in a container would complicate the code on the client side.)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I *imagine* the final usage could look something like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = ...;
PrintWriter out = ...;

// Normally the parsed user input
A a = new A( 5, "test" );

// Normally generated by validation of user input
List<Error> errors = Arrays.asList( new Error( "id", "already in use" ) );

// No write it as combined json
mapper.writeValue( out, a, error );
// ... or ...
customWrite( out, a, error );
```

EDIT2:

Currently I'm looking at two possible solutions:

1. Write a custom Serializer. Seems like a clean solution but needs to do all the stuff the default serializer does. But is a complex solution because I first have to figure out how custom serialization and extending the default works.
2. Just use String replacement and concatenation. Write both objects seperately and remove staring/closing curly braces and append one on another. Quick, but very dirty. (I really don't like this but it could work.)

Comment: At what point do you want to inject the errors?  Could you add some code for what you would want the error injecting to look like?  You could always serialize to an ObjectNode and then add it manually.  I am just trying to figure where you would want the errors data stored.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added an EDIT. I hope this makes it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do that using [`ObjectMapper.convertValue`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class%29) method. See below example:

```
A a = new A(101, "test");
List<Error> errors = Arrays.asList(new Error("id", "already in use"), new Error("value",
        "field to long"));

// Create Jackson objects
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MapType mapType = jsonMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(LinkedHashMap.class,
        String.class, Object.class);

// Create map
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = jsonMapper.convertValue(a, mapType);
map.put("__errors__", errors);

// Serialize map
String json = jsonMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map);

System.out.println(json);
```

Above example prints:

```
{
  "id" : 101,
  "value" : "test",
  "__errors__" : [ {
    "field" : "id",
    "message" : "already in use"
  }, {
    "field" : "value",
    "message" : "field to long"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know I can use Jackson to construct Maps. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!